# How to Remove Add to Cart Loading Animation Magento

Tags: magento

can anybody help me eliminate animation on the following picture when I click the "Add To Cart"? Thank You  This is the Screen Shoot http://prntscr.com/5xm527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That animation is just to notify that the ajax call is processing so after ajax complete it will be hided.

if you dont want that then just find the ajax code in js and comment the code that show and hide the loader.